# Edit Beans XML file using Interface tool in IntelliJ

Tags: xml, spring, intellij-idea

I am watching a tutorial video on Java Spring framework, and the instructor is using a nice interface to generate XML code.

Example:
[image]

I tried to search Google about something equivalent in IntelliJ IDEA but I couldn't find something.

Any ideas?